# Reindex array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [0] => Red [1] => Blue [2] => Black [3] => White [4] => Silver)
  [1] => Array ( [0] => Yellow [1] => Green [2] => Pink [3] => Purple)
  [2] => Array ( [0] => Orange [1] => Olive [2] => Lime)
etc..
)
```

Expected array:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Red
   [1] => Blue
   [2] => Black
   [3] => White
   [4] => Silver
   [5] => Yellow  
   [6] => Green
   [7] => Pink
   [8] => Purple
   [9] => Orange
   [10] => Olive
   [11] => Lime
   etc..
)
```

How to this refactoring? I can't understand

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very handy *built-in* way in php.  Array_merg is a function that will combine an unlimited number of arguments into a final array.   And call_user_func_array will automatically populate the arguments into Array_merg, so we can accomplish our goal via a one-liner:

**PHP**

```
<?php

$workwith = Array ( 
    Array("Red", "Blue", "Black", "White", "Silver"),
    Array("Yellow", "Green", "Pink", "Purple"),
    Array("Orange", "Olive", "Lime")
);

$result = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $workwith);
print_r($result);

?>
```

**Output**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Red
    [1] => Blue
    [2] => Black
    [3] => White
    [4] => Silver
    [5] => Yellow
    [6] => Green
    [7] => Pink
    [8] => Purple
    [9] => Orange
    [10] => Olive
    [11] => Lime
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `array_merge` function like this...

```
<?php
$array1 = Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [0] => Red [1] => Blue [2] => Black [3] => White [4] => Silver)
  [1] => Array ( [0] => Yellow [1] => Green [2] => Pink [3] => Purple)
  [2] => Array ( [0] => Orange [1] => Olive [2] => Lime)
etc..
)

$array2 = Array();
for($i=0; $i<$array1.length; $i++) {
    $array2 = array_merge($array2, $array1[$i]);
}

print_r($array2);
?>
```

Comment: This solution does not work correctly. `$array1.length` causes an error. change it with `count($array1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$arrayIndex = 0;
    $ar=array(
        array("red","black","blue"),
        array("Green", "Pink", "Yellow")
    );
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ar); $i++){
        for ($i1 = 0; $i1 < sizeof($ar[$i]); $i1++){
            $newArray[$arrayIndex] = $ar[$i][$i1];
            $arrayIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

using [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
array_walk_recursive($ar, function($v, $k) use (&$list) {return $list[] = $v;});
print_r($list);
```

live example: https://3v4l.org/DRMKI

Comment: This solution is so slower than the accepted answer.